# rosserial incompatable with Ardupilot?

Tags: ros, rosseral-arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to add ros support to the Ardupilot board using rosserial but I am unable to include the ros.h header from rosserial_arduino without getting weird compilation errors:

> libraries/ros_lib/ros/../rosserial_msgs/Log.h:17: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
> libraries/ros_lib/ros/../rosserial_msgs/Log.h:17: error: expected `}' before numeric constant
> libraries/ros_lib/ros/../rosserial_msgs/Log.h:17: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
> libraries/ros_lib/ros/../rosserial_msgs/Log.h:23: error: virtual outside class declaration

I'm able to compile and run rosserial examples on my Arduino just fine.
The Ardupilot code can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/ardupilot-mega/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10937/rosserial-incompatable-with-ardupilot?/) by [patrick_hammer](https://answers.ros.org/users/465/patrick_hammer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 283 on 2011-08-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Patrick.

I am unfamiliar with ardupilot, however it shouldnt give you errors like that.  If you provide a self contained example of where you are getting the error, I can help.

---

Originally posted by [adasta](https://answers.ros.org/users/52/adasta/) with karma: 508 on 2011-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1